# SQL Server query search putting a certain value match at top

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I have a query:

```
select Product.TblProducts.Product_ID, 
       Product.TblProducts.Product_Name,     
       Product.TblProducts.Country 
from Product.TblProducts 
WHERE (Product.TblProducts.Domain = 'mysite.co.uk')
```

Problem:
I want all the products to show, but I want to show products with Country = "United Kingdom" to take high priority and show at top since the domain is UK.

I need a sort mechanism to do this.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement in the `order by`:

```
select Product.TblProducts.Product_ID, Product.TblProducts.Product_Name,
       Product.TblProducts.Country 
from Product.TblProducts
WHERE  (Product.TblProducts.Domain = 'mysite.co.uk')
order by (case when Country = 'United Kingdom' then 1 else 2 end)
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
select 
    Product.TblProducts.Product_ID, 
    Product.TblProducts.Product_Name,     
    Product.TblProducts.Country 
from 
    Product.TblProducts 
    WHERE  (Product.TblProducts.Domain = 'mysite.co.uk')
order by (CASE WHEN Country = 'United Kingdom' THEN 1 else 0 end) desc
```